# init or initWithNibName not getting called when loading nib file manually

Tags: objective-c, nib, uinib

I am loading the nib file manually (for UIView reusability),
the code for loading the nib file

```
- (NSArray*)loadMyNibFile
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customView" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *topLevelObjs =  [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

    NSLog(@"objects: %@", topLevelObjs);

    return topLevelObjs;
}
```

after loading the nib name i am adding it to a UIScrollView

```
NSArray *array = [self loadMyNibFile];
CustomView *view = [array objectAtIndex:0];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2;
frame.origin.y = 99;
[view setFrame:frame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:view];
```

not the problems is that when I load the nib file this way the `init` and `initWithNibName` methods are not being called,
how could this be solved ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `[UIView initWithFrame:]` and `[UIView initWithCoder:]` methods (see the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html)).

If you always load the view from a NIB, as opposed to manual creation, it's probably better to override `awakeFromNib` (see [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).